# How to make a composite index in Postgres including a POINT?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, gist-index

With this table:

```
CREATE TABLE bins (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    bits BIT(16) NOT NULL,
    topleft POINT, -- (x,y) in web mercator projection
    count INTEGER
);
CREATE INDEX ON bins USING gist(topleft);
```

How can I create a composite index such that I can efficiently run queries such as:

```
SELECT SUM(packets) FROM bins
WHERE (start BETWEEN '2023-10-30' AND '2023-10-31')
AND bits = B'0000000000001001'
AND topleft <@ BOX '(90500000000,135800000000)(90600000000,135900000000)';
```

(Composite indices, not involving gists, are not a problem.)

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you get? (or what happened, if not an error)

Comment: @jjanes I was getting an error when I added non-POINT fields to the gist index.  Sorry, I can't remember what it was because it stopped when I used `CREATE EXTENSIONS btree_gist;` (answer below) and it has not come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index in your answer looks alright. To avoid scanning unnecessary index entries, you should put the columns where you compare with `=` first. In your case, that is `bits`.

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to use `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;` which then allowed me to use:

```
CREATE INDEX ON bins USING gist(start, bits, topleft);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: `bits` should be first.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks - if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.